# How to loop a model with it's belongsToMany relation in a table? Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I want to loop my Packages in a table (each Package has belongsToMany relation with Test Model)& I don't know how to loop in my blade?

```
public function tests()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Test');
}
```

here is my full table (blade):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th><span>Child</span></th>
            <th>Women</th>
            <th>Men</th>
            <th>Athletes</th>
            <th>VIP</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="title"><b>TestOne</b></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title"><b>TestTwo</b></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title"><b>TestThree</b></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title"><b>TestFour</b></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title"><b>TestFive</b></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title"><b>TestSix</b></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
            <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

each `<i class="fa-solid fa-check">` show the  a row of the pivot table between
and the design is:
[image]

How to loop this model with relation in my blde?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i create my table in this way via checking the relations:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="tr" width="150"></th>
            @foreach ($data['packages'] as $item)
                <th>{{$item->title}}</th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($data['tests'] as $item)
            <tr>
                <td class="title"><b>{{$item->title}}</b></td>
                @foreach ($data['packages'] as $pack)
                    @if($item->packages->contains($pack->id))
                        <td><i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i></td>
                    @else
                        <td></td>
                    @endif
                    
                @endforeach
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have actually sent your list of models to the view, you can use [blade directives](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops) like this (this is just a mock model, I don't know what your models actually looks like):

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><span>Child</span></th>
        <th>Women</th>
        <th>Men</th>
        <th>Athletes</th>
        <th>VIP</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($models as $model)
        <tr>
            <td class="title">
                <b>
                    {{ $model->title }}
                </b>
            </td>
            <td>
                @if ($model->is_child)
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                @if ($model->is_women)
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                @if ($model->is_men)
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
                @endif</td>
            <td>
                @if ($model->is_athletes)
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
                @endif
            </td>
            <td>
                @if ($model->is_vip)
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
                @endif
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The @if conditions is just me guessing. Put whatever you need to figure out if the fa-check should be rendered or not.

Usually data is sent to view something like this:

```
$data['models'] = MyModel::all();
return view('myView', $data);
```

Then you can access the variable $models in your view

Comment: Iwant to loop every tr & td tag dynamically, i need to loop in every relation & nonrelation td
please see this: https://imgur.com/u2DDxTj

Comment: You can check if a relationship returns a model or null, so like this if (!is_null($test)) for relation exist and then use else instead of another if-clause.